# SignalR connection after disconnect

Tags: vb.net, signalr

Dears, I need the SingalR to reconnect again after disconnect, is the following code is good, or there is another way:

```
Dim Proxy As IHubProxy
Dim Hub As HubConnection

Private Function ConnectToCallCenterHub()

    Try

        Hub = New HubConnection(CallCenterHubAddress)
        Proxy = Hub.CreateHubProxy("CallCenterHub")

        AddHandler Hub.StateChanged, (AddressOf HubConnectionState)

        Hub.Start()

        Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Function

Private Sub HubConnectionState(ByVal State As Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.StateChange)

    Try

        Invoke(New OnConnectionSateChangedDelegate(AddressOf OnConnectionSateChanged), State.NewState)

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

Public Delegate Function OnConnectionSateChangedDelegate(ByVal State As Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState)
Public Function OnConnectionSateChanged(ByVal State As Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState)

    Try
        If State = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState.Connected Then
            sbConnectionStatus.Text = "Connected"
            pbConnecting.Visible = False
        End If
        If State = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState.Connecting Then
            sbConnectionStatus.Text = "Connecting"
        End If
        If State = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState.Reconnecting Then
            sbConnectionStatus.Text = "Reconnecting"
        End If
        If State = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState.Disconnected Then
            sbConnectionStatus.Text = "Disconnected"
            ConnectToCallCenterHub()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Function
```

The function ConnectToCallCenterHub is called to connec to the hub, and in case of disconnect I call it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked in vb.net but according to my knowledge of signalR, to disconnect you'll need to override the disconnect method derived from HubBase.

Here's the code

```
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        if(stopCalled==true)
        {
           //your code here
        }
        else
        {
           //your code here
        }
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
```

Hope it's useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I mean that on the client side, when the state changed to Disconnected, I need to connect again automatically.

Comment: `$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});`    According to that may b this code will help. @Abusnake